# Координаты прикосновения пальца  к экрану

Tags: android, java

Есть активити. На ней `ListView` и `SlidingDrawer`. Необходимо, чтобы при всплывании панели `SlidingDrawer`, т.е. при выполнении метода `setOnDrawerOpenListener()` были прочтены координаты экрана, куда прикоснулся палец для открытия панели. Подскажите, как прочитать эти координаты. И, по ходу, второй вопрос: как можно определить какой элемент списка `ListView` соответствует найденным координатам?

Comment: отвечаю на первый вопрос: достаточно переорпеделить метод onTouchEvent() у SlidingDrawer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Берете, делаете свой ответ в коменте своем же) и пример:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    switch ( event.getAction() ) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            eventX = (int)event.getX();
            eventY = (int)event.getY();
```

getX() вернет координату экрана по Х, а другой по У соответственно.
Если я правильно понял много букв)

А ответ на второй вопрос: а зачем такое? Ну можно получить кол-во видимых элементов списка их высоту и посчитать примерно в какой области какой находится. Но зачем??? Ну да ладно)